# Adding an item in ArrayList makes previous items all the same as the newly added

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm a noob in java and I can't seem to figure out how every time I add a new item to my ArrayList the previous ones become all the same as the new one. I did everything I learned from the posts here with the same issue but i still can't seem to figure out what's really wrong. I've been in this for a week now. Hopefully, someone would help.

Here's my code:

```
private void generation(String numberOfCase,int i, int j){

    switch(numberOfCase){

    case "N":
        int tempN = 0;

        if(i == 1)
            tempN = 0;
        if(i == 2)
            tempN = 1;

        forGenerating[i][j] = current[tempN][j];
        forGenerating[tempN][j] = 0;

        State tempNo = new State(forGenerating,current,1,howFar);
        adding(tempNo);
        //adding(forGenerating,current,1,howFar);

        forGenerating[tempN][j] = forGenerating[i][j];
        forGenerating[i][j] = 0;

        break;
    case "E":
        int tempE = j+1;

        forGenerating[i][j] = current[i][tempE];
        forGenerating[i][tempE] = 0;

        State tempEa = new State(forGenerating,current,1,howFar);
        adding(tempEa);
        //adding(forGenerating,current,1,howFar);

        forGenerating[i][tempE] = forGenerating[i][j];
        forGenerating[i][j] = 0;

        break;
    case "S":
        int tempS = 0;

        if(i == 0)
            tempS = 1;
        if(i == 1)
            tempS = 2;

        forGenerating[i][j] = current[tempS][j];
        forGenerating[tempS][j] = 0;

        State tempSo = new State(forGenerating,current,1,howFar);
        adding(tempSo);
        //adding(forGenerating,current,1,howFar);

        forGenerating[tempS][j] = forGenerating[i][j];
        forGenerating[i][j] = 0;

        break;
    case "W":
        int tempW = j-1;

        forGenerating[i][j] = current[i][tempW];
        forGenerating[i][tempW] = 0;

        State tempWe = new State(forGenerating,current,1,howFar);
        adding(tempWe);
        //adding(forGenerating,current,1,howFar);

        forGenerating[i][tempW] = forGenerating[i][j];
        forGenerating[i][j] = 0;

        break;
    }

}

private void adding(State temp){

    State t = new State(temp);

    if(closedList.equals(temp) == false){

        forChecking.add(t);
        iterator+=1;

    }

}
```

I created an ArrayList of the class I've created for the states.

EDIT. Here's the class State. There are two constructors because I've been editing this code for a week now and doing all possible solutions I've read from the web.

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class State {

```
int[][] arr = new int[3][3];
int[][] parent = new int[3][3];
int g=0,f=0,h=0;

public State(int[][] arr, int[][] parent, int g, int h){

    this.arr = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length);
    this.parent = Arrays.copyOf(parent, parent.length);
    this.g = g;
    this.h = h;
    solveF();

}

public State(State temp){

    this.arr = Arrays.copyOf(temp.arr, temp.arr.length);
    this.parent = Arrays.copyOf(temp.parent, temp.parent.length);
    this.g = temp.g;
    this.h = temp.h;
    solveF();

}

private void solveF(){

    f = g+h;

}
```

}

Comment: Where's the `ArrayList`?

Comment: List<State> forChecking = new ArrayList<State>(); here, i did it like this

Comment: Nothing should go wrong with your code. The only thing I see is that when you do the new State(temp), you must be modifying a static member of your class State and that's why all your instances are modified at the same time (or at least seems to be). Can you show your class State ?

Comment: i think that's my error. And I really have no idea how to not modify the arraylist. I tried the different suggestions I learned on related topics about this problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in Java, there is an actual object called [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). Using that might simplify what you are trying to do, or at least making it easier to read as the methods of that class will have your code read like verbs.

**The values are the same because you are storing the same array in the new State object.** Consider one of the copy methods in the [Array utilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html). Later in your code you overwrite the value again, but since it's the same array object that was stored, they all look the same.

As to your code, it would be helpful to hear more of what you're trying to do. And maybe see some more surrounding code. However, some things that catch my eye:

- The input variable `numberOfCase` is a string, which is confusing because one might think that should be a number.

  - While it is possible to `switch` on a string, consider making those inputs [`Enum`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).
- In the adding() method, the code `closedList.equals(temp)` is comparing the objects. "closedList" sounds like a list or array, while "temp" is a `State`, so they will never be equal. Perhaps you meant to use `!closedList.contains(temp)`? (though be aware you'll need to Override `.equals(Object o)` in the State class)
- It looks like your code is assuming a 2x2 matrix of values, and that i or j will always be 1 or 2, corresponding to the N,S,E,W string. For that type of case, I would suggest creating your own class with straight forward method names. Perhaps something like:

  ```
  public class CompassGenerator{
    //private fields

    //returns previous Compass object, if required...
    public Compass generateNorth(int howFar){...}

    //Alternatively, pass in Compass object from which to generate
    public Compass generateSouth(Compass prev, int howFar){...}

    //etc...

  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you! I'm gonna edit those parts. This assignment is the java implementation for 8 puzzle. The closedList is an arraylist of State objects. Thank you again for the suggestions. I'll be sure to implement it in my code.